# Are multiple clients on a single AP limited to the same constellation

Tags: ieee-802.11, ap

My question is quite simple.

If I have multiple clients connected to the same radio on the same AP, is each client confined to the lowest modulation/carrier size of the weakest client?

So if I have 12 clients on a single AP, the worst one has an exceptionally poor RSSI and is at 16QAM, 20MHz, 3/4 FEC (guard interval undefined). Are all my clients limited to the worst-performing client?

As if I have a client sitting right by the AP transferring at 100 Mbps, and then I have another client transferring at 50 Mbps, one at an RSSI of -20dBi and one at an RSSI -67dBi is the best performing client limited to the worst as the radio doesn't have time to change its ASI functionality at such speed?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no - the WAP negotiates and renegotiates data rates and modulation modes/parameters with each client separately.

However, since broadcast/multicasts need to use the slowest (used or possible) mode and rate, heavy use of those impacts all clients due to the increased use of overall and shared air time.

Newer technologies like MU-MIMO somewhat decrease inter-client influences but their impact extremely depends on the overall scenario.